# Spring Security get CSRF token

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-security

I am using Spring Security 4. Everything works fine until I decided to turn on CSRF to keep website security. But I am getting confused after reading lots of relevant documents. Here is the question:

I have back-end services with Spring MVC and Spring Security running on `Computer A`, on `Computer B` I have all the front-end HTML. New I want to login in from webpages in `Computer B`, it always says `Invalid CSRF Token 'null' was found on the request parameter '_csrf' or header 'X-CSRF-TOKEN'.` I think the CSRF token is generated by `Computer A`, but how can I obtain it so that I can include it in the following request?

Thanks

Comment: were you able to find a solution to this eventually?

Answer (score 0):

Have you added following tag in your login form.

```
<input type="hidden" name="${_csrf.parameterName}" value="${_csrf.token}"/>
```

Please refer to spring documentation for more details.

http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.2.x/reference/htmlsingle/#csrf-include-csrf-token

Comment: Yes. I have tried that. Actually I think `${_csrf.token}` should be replaced with the real token when submit the request, is it right?

Comment: OK, then my question is if the token is generated by the Spring Security, how does the client computer know it? i.e., how to find the value to replace "${_csrf.token}".

Comment: Actually It is populated automatically,You just have to enable @EnableWebSecurity on your server side application.Please follow the docs http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/html/csrf.html

Comment: I have followed this tutorial exactly.

`<input type="hidden" name="${_csrf.parameterName}" value="${_csrf.token}"/>` 

is added. However,

`Invalid CSRF Token 'null' was found on the request parameter '_csrf' or header 'X-CSRF-TOKEN'.` 

is shown. Here is the form data sent:

`username:xxxxx`
`password:yyyyy`
`${_csrf.parameterName}:${_csrf.token}`
`remember-me:false`